# Unable to launch chrome via chrome webdriver on jenkins where as it works fine on my local machine

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, testing, webdriver

Unable to launch chrome via chrome webdriver on jenkins where as it works fine on my local machine. I have tried everything that is on there on the internet to solve this problem but unable to get out of this loop hole. Though it's very much irritating I have wasted a lot of time kindly help if anyone out there is familiar of this problem. As I am new to selenium testing this is very frustrating issue.

```
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Test
`using credential 9917dab9-de45-43b7-8ff2-0c2b530a0ecf
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://bitbucket.org/admitkard/akd_e2e.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://bitbucket.org/admitkard/akd_e2e.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > git fetch --tags --progress -- https://bitbucket.org/admitkard/akd_e2e.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/pawan^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/pawan^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 10f6281f501136b9ffcd504f4d8f3a54568d1162 (refs/remotes/origin/pawan)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 10f6281f501136b9ffcd504f4d8f3a54568d1162 # timeout=10
Commit message: "Hi"
 > git rev-list --no-walk 10f6281f501136b9ffcd504f4d8f3a54568d1162 # timeout=10
[Test] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins5524615085827631447.sh
+ echo /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Test
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Test
+ cd /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Test/
+ mvn clean test -DtestngFile=testng/signupTestng.xml -Durl=https://dev.admitkard.net/ -Dbrowser=chrome
[[1;34mINFO[m] Scanning for projects...
[[1;33mWARNING[m] 
[[1;33mWARNING[m] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.example.admitKard:admitKard:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[[1;33mWARNING[m] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 27, column 21
[[1;33mWARNING[m] 
[[1;33mWARNING[m] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[[1;33mWARNING[m] 
[[1;33mWARNING[m] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[[1;33mWARNING[m] 
[[1;34mINFO[m] 
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m------------------< [0;36mcom.example.admitKard:admitKard[0;1m >-------------------[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1mBuilding admitKard 1.0-SNAPSHOT[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m--------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------[m
[[1;33mWARNING[m] The artifact org.apache.commons:commons-io:jar:1.3.2 has been relocated to commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.3.2
[[1;34mINFO[m] 
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m--- [0;32mmaven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean[m [1m(default-clean)[m @ [36madmitKard[0;1m ---[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] Deleting /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Test/target
[[1;34mINFO[m] 
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m--- [0;32mmaven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources[m [1m(default-resources)[m @ [36madmitKard[0;1m ---[m
[[1;33mWARNING[m] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[[1;34mINFO[m] skip non existing resourceDirectory /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Test/src/main/resources
[[1;34mINFO[m] 
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m--- [0;32mmaven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile[m [1m(default-compile)[m @ [36madmitKard[0;1m ---[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] No sources to compile
[[1;34mINFO[m] 
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m--- [0;32mmaven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources[m [1m(default-testResources)[m @ [36madmitKard[0;1m ---[m
[[1;33mWARNING[m] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[[1;34mINFO[m] Copying 16 resources
[[1;34mINFO[m] 
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m--- [0;32mmaven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile[m [1m(default-testCompile)[m @ [36madmitKard[0;1m ---[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[[1;33mWARNING[m] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[[1;34mINFO[m] Compiling 53 source files to /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Test/target/test-classes
[[1;33mWARNING[m] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Test/src/test/java/admitKard/testcases/StudentProfileTest.java: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Test/src/test/java/admitKard/testcases/StudentProfileTest.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
[[1;33mWARNING[m] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Test/src/test/java/admitKard/testcases/StudentProfileTest.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[[1;34mINFO[m] 
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m--- [0;32mmaven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M3:test[m [1m(default-test)[m @ [36madmitKard[0;1m ---[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] 
[[1;34mINFO[m] -------------------------------------------------------
[[1;34mINFO[m]  T E S T S
[[1;34mINFO[m] -------------------------------------------------------
[[1;34mINFO[m] Running [1mTestSuite[m
Feb 19, 2020 11:39:25 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities chrome
INFO: Using `new ChromeOptions()` is preferred to `DesiredCapabilities.chrome()`
Starting ChromeDriver 80.0.3987.106 (f68069574609230cf9b635cd784cfb1bf81bb53a-refs/branch-heads/3987@{#882}) on port 24340
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeSuite setDriver
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z'
System info: host: 'latitude-e7450', ip: '192.168.0.72', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.3.0-28-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_242'
Driver info: driver.version: Set_Driver
remote stacktrace: #0 0x561a34250d29 <unknown>

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$new$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:57)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:104)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:122)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:486)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:531)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:125)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:73)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:212)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:130)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:157)
    at admitKard.base.BaseUIPage.initWebsiteDriver(BaseUIPage.java:72)
    at admitKard.base.Set_Driver.setDriver(Set_Driver.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:62)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:340)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:294)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:345)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:304)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1180)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1102)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1032)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1000)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:384)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:345)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:418)

SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod register
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterMethod afterMethod
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod register
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterMethod afterMethod
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod register
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterMethod afterMethod
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod register
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterMethod afterMethod
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod register
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterMethod afterMethod
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod register
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterMethod afterMethod
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod register
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterMethod afterMethod
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod register
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterMethod afterMethod
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod register
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterMethod afterMethod
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod register
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterMethod afterMethod
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod register
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterMethod afterMethod
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod register
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterMethod afterMethod
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod register
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterMethod afterMethod
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod register
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterMethod afterMethod
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod register
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterMethod afterMethod
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod register
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterMethod afterMethod
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod register
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterMethod afterMethod
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod register
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterMethod afterMethod
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod register
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterMethod afterMethod
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod register
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterMethod afterMethod
SKIPPED: verifyClickRegisterTab
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z'
System info: host: 'latitude-e7450', ip: '192.168.0.72', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.3.0-28-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_242'
Driver info: driver.version: Set_Driver
remote stacktrace: #0 0x561a34250d29 <unknown>

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$new$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:57)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:104)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:122)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:486)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:531)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:125)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:73)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:212)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:130)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:157)
    at admitKard.base.BaseUIPage.initWebsiteDriver(BaseUIPage.java:72)
    at admitKard.base.Set_Driver.setDriver(Set_Driver.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:62)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:340)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:294)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:345)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:304)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1180)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1102)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1032)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1000)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:384)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:345)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:418)
```

This is before suite :-

```
`@BeforeSuite
    public void setDriver() throws Exception {

            BaseUIPage bp = new BaseUIPage();

            //Generate HTML Report
            htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/AutomationReports.html"));
            htmlReporter.loadXMLConfig(
                    String.valueOf(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/test/resources/runner/extent-config.xml")));
            reports = new ExtentReports();
            reports.setSystemInfo("Environment", "Local");
            reports.setSystemInfo("Website Name", "AdmitKard");
            reports.attachReporter(htmlReporter);

            //Read Data from data properties file
            dataFileProperties = new Properties();
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(
                    System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/test/resources/properties/datafile.properties");
            dataFileProperties.load(fis);

        if (wDriver == null) {
            //Initialize web driver and Launch Website
            WEB_URL = System.getProperty("url");
            BROWSER = System.getProperty("browser");
            if(WEB_URL == null)
            {
                WEB_URL = dataFileProperties.getProperty("URL");
                BROWSER = dataFileProperties.getProperty("browser");
            }
            wDriver = bp.initWebsiteDriver(wDriver, WEB_URL, BROWSER);
        }
            //Set web driver in base UI page
            bp.setWebDriver(wDriver);

        //driver set for multiple browser
        multipleBrowser = System.getProperty("secondBrowser");
//        if(multipleBrowser == null){
//        multipleBrowser = dataFileProperties.getProperty("secondBrowser");}
        if(multipleBrowser!= null && multipleBrowser.equals("true")){
            secondDriver = bp.initWebsiteDriver(secondDriver, WEB_URL, BROWSER);
            bp.setSecondWebDriver(secondDriver);
        }
        //MyScreenRecorder.startRecording("AutomationTest");
     }`
```

This is webdriver initalization code :-

```
 `public WebDriver initWebsiteDriver(WebDriver cDriver, String WEB_URL, String Browser) throws NullPointerException
    {

        if(Browser.equalsIgnoreCase("Chrome"))
        {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/browserDriver/chromedriver");


            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.logfile", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/browserDriver/chromedriver.log");
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.verboseLogging", "true");

            //Set path for download file
            String downloadFilepath = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/src/test/resources/download";
            HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
            chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadFilepath);
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
            DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
            cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
            cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
            options.setBinary("/usr/bin/google-chrome");
            options.addArguments("--no-sandbox"); //https://stackoverflow.com/a/50725918/1689770
            options.addArguments("disable-features=NetworkService");
            options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
            options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
            options.addArguments("--remote-debugging-port=9222");
           // ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
            options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
           // options.addArguments("--headless");
           // options.setHeadless(true);
            options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
            options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
            cDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
            //cDriver=new RemoteWebDriver(cap);
        }
        else if(Browser.equalsIgnoreCase("Firefox"))
        {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/browserDriver/geckodriver");
            FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
            profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/test/resources/download"
                     + File.separator);

            FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
            firefoxOptions.setProfile(profile);


            //firefoxOptions.addPreference("dom.webnotifications.enabled",false);
            cDriver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);
        }
        else if(Browser.equalsIgnoreCase("safari"))
        {
            cDriver = new SafariDriver();
        }
        cDriver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1680, 900));
        cDriver.get(WEB_URL);
        cDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        return cDriver;
    }`
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
--remote-debugging-port=9222
```

to your chrome driver options

Comment: Still the problem persists.

Comment: please provide your before method and webdriver initalization code

Comment: Sir I have added these two sections of code requested ny you kindly take a look on them. Thanks in advance

Comment: the debug port option should have fixed it, not sure i can help without going in to debug. the easiest way you can attempt to fix it, is to remove all options and capabilities for the chrome driver, leaving only the debug one, see if that fixes the problem, and, i advice to improve your code by using 
 https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager